# A rack-supporting webserver that runs in JRuby and supports SSL and streaming

Tags: ssl, webserver, jruby, rack

I'm having issues looking for a rack supporting webserver in Ruby that meets our requirements. What we've coded already is using Sinatra, so that's what we're aiming to run.

The webservice must:

- Run in JRuby
- Support SSL
- support streaming of files.  It's much more important to be memory-efficient than performant.
- Be Multiplatform (Windows and Linux flavours)
- As lightweight as possible - links back to memory efficiency

We're currently using WEBrick, but it can't handle streaming, so we're looking for alternatives.  I've been looking around myself, but I'm having real difficulty finding documentation about what various rack webservers can and can't do.  The services I've looked at are:

- WEBrick - doesn't support streaming
- Thin - depends on C code, so doesn't run in JRuby
- Passenger - ditto Thin (C Code)
- Unicorn - ditto Thin (C Code)

We're aware that it could be deployed J2EE container, but as that would require distributing the container around with it, we'd rather not go down that approach if we can avoid it (as it would be a heavier weight solution).

Thanks in advance for any help people can give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who finds this question and wants to know what we used in the end:  we went with [Trinidad](https://github.com/trinidad/trinidad) as it met all the requirements we needed.

It was quite a simple job to strip out the original WEBrick server we were using and replace it with Trinidad, while still using [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/).  We then used JRuby to wrap it all up into a Jar and run it in the JVM as a self contained web-service package.

Answer (score 0):

Does [Puma](https://github.com/puma/puma) meet your requirements? It supports JRuby, SSL, Windows + Linux, and advertises itself as lightweight. I'm afraid I haven't tried it out, nor do I know if it streams files.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying.

We did look at Puma but ended up not using it - I'm afraid I've lost my notes now, so I can't remember why we didn't use it.

In the end we went with [Trinidad](https://github.com/trinidad/trinidad), which is working fine and doing everything we required of it.  I found it quite fiddly to get setup and playing nicely with Sinatra, but once the config was sorted out it worked well.

Comment: Puma only recently added support for SSL when running under JRuby, so that may have been why? We'll take a look at Trinidad as well and see if either fits our needs :) p.s. it'd be nice if you wrote up an answer to your own question :)

Comment: Sorry, my bad - had actually forgotten I'd written this question.  I'll write up an answer now.  Thanks for trying to help